# Can Mushin No Shin be played on any card?

Tags: android-netrunner

Thanks for reading: 
[Mushin No shin](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05015) can be used to advance cards; I assume that that these 
cards are only assets, upgrades or agendas that can be advanced. Does this mean that I can place advancement tokens on assets or upgrades that cannot be advanced, to trick the runner? Or is this move not legal?

Thank you,
Suman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ability is:

> Install an asset, agenda, or upgrade from HQ in a new remote server.
>   Place 3 advancement tokens on that card. You cannot score or rez that
>   card until your next turn begins.

Unlike cards like [Shipment from Kaguya](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01100), [Mushin No Shin](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05015) has no restriction here that the card must be a card that can be advanced.

Thus, any card that can be installed in a remote server, namely any Agenda, Asset, or Upgrade, is a valid choice.  For example, you could use Mushin No Shin on a [Snare!](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01070)

Comment: Yeah, the key here is that it doesn't advance the card, but rather puts 3 advancement tokens on it - subtle difference, but was a facepalm for me once it was pointed out.

Comment: @AndrewVandever Not exactly. Shipment from Kaguya doesn't advance the card either, there is actually no card in Netrunner that advances other cards, only the advancement action advances cards.

Comment: @Andrew, you are almost correct. :) There is exactly one card that advances other cards: https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/12078. Anyway, my point was just that the Advance action has the rule, "Cards other than agendas can only be advanced if their text box allows it.", which does not apply to Mushin No Shin.